# Can not insert child view into Android Studio's layout editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Does Android Studio support inserting a views into custom layouts by drag&drop, such as CoordinatorLayout or my custom layouts? Now it seems like layout editor detects such layouts like simple views, which can not have children.

Answer (score 0):

All views that extend the `ViewGroup` class can have children. It does not matter whether it's a custom view or not. [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) is no exception.

Comment: I edited my question. I mean that can I insert view by drag&drop.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this by drag & drop? Editing the layouts via code not much harder, not to mention that its faster and more efficient than drag and drop.